# Error in Table Creation in DynamoDB using Python Visual Studio

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I tried creating a `table` in `Dynamo DB` using Python `Visual Studio`, but I have been getting this error message:

```
"An error occurred (IncompleteSignatureException) when calling the CreateTable 
operation: 'AWS' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization 
header: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXX AWS Secret Access Key [None]:XXX
```

Please can someone help me with how to navigate through this error.

I have tried disabling my AWS users account, and also enabling console access, but neither worked.

It seems I have to add a key to my code, but I dont know how to go about it.